# How to parse strings into time ranges in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

```
time_ranges = ['Sunday-Thursday: 5:00 pm - 8:00 pm', 'Friday - Saturday: 1:00 pm - 2:00 pm']
```

Is there a simple way to turn the likes of a list of strings shown above into datetime ranges? Is there a package or library that would make this task easy?

Comment: A datetime needs a date, not just a day of the week. They don't model what you're trying to model.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to what I could use to model days of the week?

Comment: Well modeling just the days of the week can be done in several trivial ways depending on how you use them. But I am guessing you mean modelling business hour type ranges during the days of the week...in such a case I would say create your own class or classes to model it. The best specific approach would vary a lot with the particular features you needed to solve your problem. I am afraid you will have to give more details for people to be more help here.

Comment: Show your desired results. What `datetime` objects should be produced?

Comment: My end goal is to have users be able to come to my site and if the time at which they visit falls into one of the day/time ranges, I will add a note that says "This store is open!" or something like that. I need to parse out the time from one of many lists like the one I've posted so I can compare the hours of operation to the time at which users visit the site

Comment: @MikeMüller, for the above list, I think I would need 7 date objects like [Sunday, (5:00PM, 8:00PM)], [Monday, (5:00PM, 8:00PM)], etc. one for each day of the week. And then I could compare the current time to the 7 time ranges and see if the current time falls within any of the ranges. I could just parse it out myself, but I wanted to know if there was an easier way to do this

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with lists --- it's entirely about parsing a string and creating an object to hold its information.  You might want to [edit] your question to remove all the talk about lists, because whatever function or class you end up writing will handle only one string at a time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it using a list of business hours:

```
import datetime
Now = datetime.datetime.now()
business_hours = [(8,18),(8,18),(12,18),(8,18),(8,20),(8,20),(-1,-1)]
for i in range(6):
    Now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    if Now.hour >= business_hours[Now.weekday()][0]\
        and Now.hour <= business_hours[Now.weekday()][1]:
        print Now.strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y"), "The store is open"
    else:
        print Now.strftime("%a %d-%m-%Y"), "The Store is closed"
```

Results:

```
Sun 13-12-2015 The Store is closed
Mon 14-12-2015 The store is open
Tue 15-12-2015 The store is open
Wed 16-12-2015 The Store is closed
Thu 17-12-2015 The store is open
Fri 18-12-2015 The store is open
```

Obviously this example attempts to prove the point using multiple dates, for your purposes, you would dump the `for range` loop and just test `Now`.
Beware of the difference between `weekday` and `isoweekday` which treat the first day of the week, Monday or Sunday, differently i.e. `weekday` where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6 and `isoweekday` where Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7